# New Screen in Laptop, Resolution Issue

Tags: laptop, display, resolution

I'm a regular at Stackoverflow; this is my first time out in the Stack Exchange.

I have a Sager NP9130 laptop.  I had a 1920x1080 resolution.

Recently my screen was cracked, and I grabbed a screen from a local PC repair shop to replace it.  I'm currently using it, and it works great, but I can't seem to get the resolution past 1366x768.  I've tried everything that Google and I can think of (update drivers) to no avail.  And sadly, I didn't write down the model of the screen I purchased before I installed it.

So, I'm wondering if it's possible that this 15.6" LED screen has a max resolution of 1366x768, or if there's any hope.  If it's worth me taking the laptop apart again to get the model number,  let me know.

Thank you so much in advance, if you need any more information I'm ready to assist.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to be specific to the screen itself.  I once replaced a HP Compaq NX6320 screen with that from a NX6120 (it was all we had at the time) and while it used to go to 1280x1024, it stopped at 1024x768.  It was a laptop that was used for heavy machinery diagnostics so it was barely a minor loss.

Depending on how badly you want the 1920x1080 resolution, it might be worth comparing model numbers to see if you can get a screen that suits.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no experience in laptops, I assume that [MultiRes](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/multires.shtm) doesn't hurt to try.